# Definition and example of a bounded lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

I understood what a lattice is and I read about some examples.
I understod what a semilattice is, what a complete lattice is but I don't know why I find some difficulties to get the concept of a bouned lattice.
Maybe it's because its very own name confuses me.
What does "bounded" mean?
If you look into [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure), it will just definite it as "a lattice with a greatest element and least element".
It would help to see some example like:

1. A lattice that is bounded but it's not complete
2. A lattice that is bounded and it's complete
3. A lattice that isn't bounded and it's not complete
4. A lattice that isn't bounded but it's complete

I know some examples are already discussed in other posts but they did not make it click for me, and, moreover, it would be much more intuitive to have all  the cases in the same place so we can easily compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A bounded, yet not complete lattice: take the set $\{-1/n:n\geq 1\} \cup \{1/n:n\geq 1\}$ with the order inherited from $\mathbb Q$. It is bounded, with least element $-1$ and greatest element $1$. Yet, it is not complete: the subset of negative numbers doesn't have a supremum within that set; likewise, the set of positive numbers doesn't have an infimum.
2. Bounded and complete: just take any powerset lattice.
3. Neither bounded nor complete: take the natural numbers with the usual order.
4. Not bounded but complete: there is no such thing. If a lattice $L$ is complete, then it is bounded by $0_L = \bigwedge L$ and $1_L = \bigvee L$.